# How to put one record of every different TypeId in a table into a list, C#, FluidAPI/LINQ, EFCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have a table in my database, (Table A), where I need to get one record from every different subset derived from selecting off a foreign key. Implementing this w/o LINQ is of course very easy, but I am curious as to how you can do this in LINQ...

EX

Table B is the other table in the relationship, A.type_id = B.Id
All records of Table A have an TypeId, with there being 3 distinct types, m,n,z.

Table A's Records -
m,
m,
m,
m,
n,
n,
n,
n,
n,
n,
z,
z,
z,
z,
z,
z,
z

WHERE(...conditions).ToList()

Needed output:
DISTINCT A(m), DISTINCT A(n), DISTINCT A(z)

Includes are not an option.

Probably was a bit verbose in explaining this...

Comment: Can you show your code so far and what's going wrong?

Comment: I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just looking to get a distinct set of values (m,n,z) 
have you tried something like this?
result = EFDBContext.TableA.Select(a => a.TypeId).Distinct();

Answer (score 0):

Got the expected result with

```
List<Program> ps = context.Programs
                    .GroupBy(t=>t.ProgramTemplateId)
                    .Select(m=>m.Last())
                    .Where(p=>!p.Active).ToList();
```